# Key Store Alias

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore

I'm trying to upload a game to Google, I've already uploaded version one, so I have to jump through frustrating hoops to get version 2 signed. It won't allow me to create a key Store alias or whatever, all the information I've put into the game is Company (com.DefaultCompany.Blaster) and Skies Above as name, but before when I filled the information out I was getting certification errors so I've restarted the project. This is the most frustrating thing I've ever had to do and have spent well over 5 hours trying to figure it out. Could someone run me through trying to get a signed APK with the right certification so I can upload my game? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)?

Comment: What kind of certification errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you setted the Key Store path as an apk file instead of a jks file (as shown below from [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)) which should be kept in a safe directory at all times since the keystore is what provides access to the apk release process after all. That said, you may need to release a new apk with the new keystore jks file, and yes, that means publishing a new listing for your app at the Play Console.
[image]